# Locationmanger startupdating location issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, location, core-location

I am updating my device location using CoreLocation

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

   CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
   double speed = loc.speed;
   NSLog(@"speed-----%f ", speed);
    }
```

When I test it with simulator it updates every seconds and I am getting the speed (By giving simulator location Freeway Drive)
But when I test with real device it updates location in an interval of 10-15 seconds.
Why this happens, Please help me ?

Comment: You should try to set the "pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically" property to NO. So, self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO; Default value is YES and in that case LocationManager stops updating locations when "it thinks" location is unlikely to change.

Comment: Thanks man It worked. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to set the "pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically" property to NO. So, `self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;`

Default value is YES and in that case LocationManager stops updating locations when "it thinks" location is unlikely to change.